# How to add outline to the active text in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have used canvas in the html5 using fabric js .
I want to apply outlines to the active text on the canvas. following code I have written it is working fine but problem is when I increase the thickness of outline then it overlaps on the text that means text color disappears.

```
activeObject1.stroke = color;
activeObject1.strokeWidth = 5;
```

and one more thing by applying this I am unable to apply 2nd outline.
I got one example but it is not working with the fabricjs.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/vNWn6/
```

Comment: Fabric supports only 1 stroke pass. _"when I increase the thickness of outline then it overlaps on the text"_ Yes, it grows inwards. You can increase text size to counter it.

Comment: but it will not look like increase in outline

Comment: why linewidth property does not support to the activeobjects  in fabric js?

Comment: any solutions yet? I am struggling too.

Answer (score 4):

```js
fabric.Text.prototype.set({
    fill: '#000',
    stroke: '#fff',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    paintFirst: 'stroke', // stroke behind fill
})
```

since [2017-09-17](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/commit/0fc71349a602fef23d427ef2a3f5cc18f7bc3c55#diff-51fecb821a761337c0acb13b64cdbd68R407)

Comment: paintFirst: 'stroke' ---> very useful for making outline stroke

Answer (score 3):

Fabric.js first applies a fill, followed by the stroke. You will need to invert the order in order to achieve the results.

```
 original
  _renderText: function(ctx) {
  this._renderTextFill(ctx);
  this._renderTextStroke(ctx);
  }
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKZU.png)

```
  modified
   _renderText: function(ctx) {
  this._renderTextStroke(ctx);
  this._renderTextFill(ctx);
  }
```

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hf3r.png)

version: fabric-1-7-1.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var active_obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
active_obj.stroke = '#000';
active_obj.strokeWidth = 5;
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.